# Can I know if a polymorphic object implements an arbitrary abstract class?

Tags: c++, c++11

This question came up in a class I was attending.  Consider:

```
class foo{virtual void foo_fun() = 0;};

class bar{virtual void bar_fun() = 0;};

template<typename T>
bool is_a_bar(T* f) {
    // I don't know baz.
    // Can I somehow know if f implements bar, T being any other type?
}

class baz : public foo, public bar {
    void foo_fun() override {}
    void bar_fun() override {}
};

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    foo* a{new baz};
    if (is_a_bar(a))  // Will call is_a_bar(foo*)
        std::cout << "a is also a bar\n";
}
```

Is it possible to know if an arbitrary object, deriving from `foo` or `bar`, also derives from the other...without knowing what the actual object is?

*(Assume that I can't change `foo` or `bar` to provide this information.)*

Comment: Does this have to work if `T` is `void`?

Comment: You can test for if something can behave "as a type" with [dynamic_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast).  If you get NULL back from that, then it cannot behave as that type.  Perhaps you can explain what you want which cannot be addressed via that?  What do you want at compile time vs. runtime?

Comment: @user2357112, not really, no. If some solution works for any class pointers but not void pointers, it's fine. (We can just use a static assertion if someone tries to call this using a `void*`)

Comment: @HostileFork at compile time is not possible, since the actual object passed to the function will only be known at runtime. Doesn't reinterpret_cast have UB if I try to cast a (in this example) `foo` to a `bar`?

Comment: @CássioRenan You caught me in the less than one minute timeframe where I corrected my mistyping of reinterpret_cast to dynamic_cast :-)  Typo/brain-failure.  I program in too many languages.

Comment: @HostileFork, Somehow I thought `dynamic_cast` only worked from base to derived or vice-versa. Probably I should re-read the reference for it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I must admit I'm not entirely sure this is what you're looking for, but you can reduce the candidacy of said-function to only play nice with polymorphic classes using SFINAE, and utilize `dynamic_cast<>` to query what you're looking for.

Something like:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_polymorphic<T>::value,bool>::type
is_a_bar(T* f)
{
    return dynamic_cast<bar const*>(f) != nullptr;
}
```

Any use of `void*` or some non-polymorphic `T` will puke at compile-time (and that obviously includes `void`).

Best of luck.

Answer (score 5):

If you compile your code with RTTI you can use dynamic_cast:

```
template<typename T>
bool is_a_bar(T* f) {
    return dynamic_cast<bar*>(f) != nullptr;
}
```